# Get HTTPS content in HTTP

Tags: java

I have a web site its some pages are in HTTP and some other in HTTPS. I need to get the value of HTTPS at HTTP page. I am using Java and Tomcat 7. Actually I got the value in JSP pages using `request.getparameter()`. But in that spaces and '@' symbols are like encrypted values showing some extra symbols. Can any please say how to solve the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: need a little bit more info to understand your question. perhaps share some code.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection`. Follow the below example:

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.io.*;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException;

public class HttpsClient{

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
        new HttpsClient().testIt();
   }

   private void testIt(){
      String https_url = "https://www.google.com/";
      URL url;

      try {
        url = new URL(https_url);
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();

        //dumpl all cert info
        print_https_cert(con);

        //dump all the content
        print_content(con);
      } 
      catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } 
      catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

   private void print_https_cert(HttpsURLConnection con){
    if(con!=null){
      try {
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + con.getResponseCode());
        System.out.println("Cipher Suite : " + con.getCipherSuite());
        System.out.println("\n");

        Certificate[] certs = con.getServerCertificates();
        for(Certificate cert : certs){
           System.out.println("Cert Type : " + cert.getType());
           System.out.println("Cert Hash Code : " + cert.hashCode());
           System.out.println("Cert Public Key Algorithm : " + cert.getPublicKey().getAlgorithm());
           System.out.println("Cert Public Key Format : " + cert.getPublicKey().getFormat());
           System.out.println("\n");
        }
      } 
      catch (SSLPeerUnverifiedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } 
      catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }

  private void print_content(HttpsURLConnection con){
    if(con!=null){
      try {
        System.out.println("****** Content of the URL ********");      
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()) );

        String input;

        while ((input = br.readLine()) != null){
           System.out.println(input);
        }

        br.close();
      } 
      catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Response Code : 200
Cipher Suite : SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA

Cert Type : X.509
Cert Hash Code : 7810131
Cert Public Key Algorithm : RSA
Cert Public Key Format : X.509

Cert Type : X.509
Cert Hash Code : 6042770
Cert Public Key Algorithm : RSA
Cert Public Key Format : X.509

****** Content of the URL ********
<!doctype html><html><head><meta http-equiv="content-type" ......
```

Comment: "Something goes wrong" this content is coming as result

Comment: this answer is an exact copy of this site's example:https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-url-content-in-java/