# How do I work with the Expedia XML API in Java

Tags: java, api

I am having the Expedia account for getting a hotel list, and they giving the XML format data.

I need to process the XML and display HTML formatted data on my website using the Java programming language. I used the file_get_contents in PHP, but I don't know about penny of link to API in Java. What would be an elaborate explanation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below will read the page contents as `file_get_contents` in php

```
   import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;


public class URLExp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            URL google = new URL("http://www.google.com/");
            URLConnection yc = google.openConnection();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc
                    .getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(inputLine);

            }
            in.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Now after passing your url in the code you should get the xml as you said. Parse the XML and use it.

Comment: This http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html provides documentation for HTTPS. Here's an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9799638/get-https-content-in-http

Answer (score 0):

Use apache httpclient to invoke the URL, get the XML by setting headers as text /XML. Easiest way to parse the XML is to use castor library. Post your code and we can help more...